# Find the maximum value of a, such that $f^2+g^2 \ge a$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the maximum possible a $\in \mathbb{R}$, such that exist two times differentiable nondecreasing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

1) $f^2(x)+g^2(x)\geq a$

2)$f''(x)=g(x)$ and $g''(x)=f(x)$

3)$f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is linear function of $x$.

---

$f''''(x)=g''(x)=f(x)$. Am I right?

The only function that being differentiated several times gives itself is $\cos(x)$. But four times...?

Comment: $m(x)*e^x*e^x$ may be linear function of x ?

Comment: I highly doubt you can find such a function that satisfies (3)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the given conditions hold in $\mathbb R$.

Since $fg$ is linear, differentiate twice to obtain $f''g+2f'g'+fg''=0$, therefore $g^2+2f'g'+f^2=0$. Differentiate again, to obtain that $2gg'+2f''g'+2f'g''+2ff'=0$, which implies that $$gg'+ ff'=0.$$ Hence, $f^2+g^2$ is equal to a constant $c_1$, and if $f(x)g(x)=c_2x$, it should hold that $$2|c_2x|=2|f(x)g(x)|\leq f^2(x)+g^2(x)=c_1,$$ therefore $c_2=0$, hence $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

We now claim that $f(0)=0$. If not, then $f$ is nonzero around $0$, and since $fg\equiv 0$, $g$ must vanish in a neighborhood of $0$. Since $f=g''$, this shows that $f(0)=0$, a contradiction. Similarly, $g(0)=0$, and since $f^2+g^2$ is a constant, the maximum value for $a$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

From $2$ and $3$, we get that $$f(x)f''(x) = x$$
This is a nonlinear ODE with no closed-form solution. So, you're out of luck for a closed-form solution.

Comment: That doesn't mean we can't prove something about $a$. It didn't ask for the most general $f$ or $g$.